# No installation candidate

Tags: linux, apt, package-management

Today I installed Debian 11. I can not install any package on it:

```
sudo apt install make .
sudo apt install build-essential
```

and any other package I go on "`Package "name" has no installation candidate` "

Comment: a) I ask this upfront: Debian 11 is already the *oldstable*, i.e., obsoleting, version of Debian. Did you install Debian 11 by mistake or intentional? b) what is the `.` doing there after `make`? Is that a typo? c) have you run `sudo apt update` before running these commands?

Comment: ... it might be helpful to run `sudo apt update` again regardless, and add the output to your question so we can see what repositories it hits

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem in these steps:

1- `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

add this

2-   `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free`

save and exit, then:

3- `debian@debian:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

4- `debian@debian:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Or any of the other packages

Comment: You would be better reinstalling with Debian 12. Your solution will get you bullseye packages but you haven't configured in security updates, for example

Comment: A `dist-upgrade` from bullseye to bookworm might take less time, and also be instructive.

Comment: If this was the solution, then your problem was that somehow during installation you did not populate `/etc/apt/sources.list` which is... Not something I've ever seen happen. Just how did you install Debian?

Comment: Firstly `nano` is not everyone's favourite editor - indeed not everyone even knows that it _is_ an editor. Secondly it's generally preferable not to grant root privilege to a general-purpose editor, so raather than `sudo nano`, a better recommendation  would be `sudoedit` (and no, that's no a typo for `sudo edit`). Thirdly, please use markdown to generate a number list.